# Parsing irregular character strings for numbers and put into structured format using regular expressions in R

Tags: regex, r

I have a vector of irregularly-structured character data, that I want to find an extract particular numbers from.  For example, take this piece of a much larger dataset:

```
x <- c("2001 Tax @ $25.19/Widget, 2002 Est Tax @ $10.68/Widget; 2000 Est Int @ $55.67/Widget",
       "1999 Tax @ $81.16/Widget",
       "1998 Tax @ $52.72/Widget; 2001 Est Int @ $62.49/Widget",
       "1994 Combined Tax/Int @ $68.33/widget; 1993 Est Int @ $159.67/Widget",
       "1993 Combined Tax/Int @ $38.33/widget; 1992 Est Int @ $159.67/Widget",
       "2006 Tax @ $129.21/Widget, 1991 Est Tax @ $58.19/Widget; 1991 Est Int @ $30.95/Widget")
```

and so on. Reading the table for a larger vector shows that most of the entries are separated by semi-colons or commas, and that there are only a limited number of terms used -- the year, Tax, Int,  Combined, Est -- with occasional variations in entries (like ";" versus ",", or "Widget" versus "widget").

I'd like to extract each of the numbers related to the terms above into a more structured data table, such as:

```
    [id]  [year] [number] [cat]  [est]
    row1  2001    25.19    Tax
    row1  2002    10.68    Tax    Est
    row1  2000    55.67    Int    Est
    row2  1999    81.16    Tax
    row3  1998    52.72    Tax
    row3  2001    62.49    Int    Est
    ....
```

or else maybe a more compact / sparse representation like:

```
    [id] [1999tax]   [2001tax]  [2002esttax]   [2000estint]
    row1 0            25.19      10.68          55.67
    row2 81.16        0          0              0
```

If that makes sense -- I ultimately need to put this into a regression model.

My first approach has been to write the following pseudocode:

1. split strings into list using strsplit() on ";" or ","
2. extract all years
3. operate on list elements using function that extracts numbers between "$" and "/"
4. return structured table columns

So far, I've only gotten this far:

```
pieces.of.x <- strsplit(x1, "[;,]"); head(pieces.of.x)
```

which gives:

```
[[1]]
[1] "2001 Tax @ $25.19/Widget"      " 2002 Est Tax @ $10.68/Widget" " 2000 Est Int @ $55.67/Widget"
[[2]]
[1] "1999 Tax @ $81.16/Widget"
[[3]]
[1] "1998 Tax @ $52.72/Widget"      " 2001 Est Int @ $62.49/Widget"
[[4]]
[1] "1994 Combined Tax/Int @ $68.33/widget" " 1993 Est Int @ $159.67/Widget"       
[[5]]
[1] "1993 Combined Tax/Int @ $38.33/widget" " 1992 Est Int @ $159.67/Widget"       
[[6]]
[1] "2006 Tax @ $129.21/Widget"     " 1991 Est Tax @ $58.19/Widget" " 1991 Est Int @ $30.95/Widget"
```

Unfortunately, I don't have the knowledge of both lapply() and regular expressions ("regex") in R, to make a procedure that is robust enough to extract the years, operate on each sub-vector of elements, and then return them.

Thanks in advance for reading.

Comment: You can extract all the relevant information with  
`gsub("[^(0-9(.?)0-9)|(((Tax)|(Int))|(Est))]", " ", x)` and then use `strsplit` on that with `split = " t| n"`.  That's as far as I've gotten yet. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The stringr package is pretty useful when dealing with strings, and I bet that someone could even make a single matcher to extract named capture group to get a similar solution...

[edit: missed the combined entries]

```
library(stringr)
library(data.table)

# Split the row entries
x <- strsplit(x, "[,;]")

# Generate the entry identifiers.
i <- 0
id <- unlist( sapply( x, function(r) rep(i<<-i+1, length(r) ) ) )

# Extract the desired values
x <- unlist( x, recursive = FALSE )
year.re <- "(^\\s?([[:digit:]]{4})\\s)"
value.re <- "[$]([[:digit:]]+[.][[:digit:]]{2})[/]"
object.re <- "[/]([[:alnum:]]+)$"
Cats<- c("Tax","Int","Combination")

x <- lapply( x, function(str) {
  c( Year=str_extract( str, year.re),
     Category=Cats[ grepl( "Tax", str)*1 + grepl( "Int", str)*2 ],
     Estimate=grepl( "Est", str),
     Value=str_match( str, value.re)[2],
     Object=str_match( str, object.re)[2] )
})

# Create a data object.
data.table( ID=id, do.call(rbind,x), key=c("Year") )

##     ID   Year    Category Estimate  Value Object
##  1:  6  1991          Tax     TRUE  58.19 Widget
##  2:  6  1991          Int     TRUE  30.95 Widget
##  3:  5  1992          Int     TRUE 159.67 Widget
##  4:  4  1993          Int     TRUE 159.67 Widget
##  5:  5  1993  Combination    FALSE  38.33 widget
##  6:  4  1994  Combination    FALSE  68.33 widget
##  7:  3  1998          Tax    FALSE  52.72 Widget
##  8:  2  1999          Tax    FALSE  81.16 Widget
##  9:  1  2000          Int     TRUE  55.67 Widget
## 10:  3  2001          Int     TRUE  62.49 Widget
## 11:  1  2001          Tax    FALSE  25.19 Widget
## 12:  1  2002          Tax     TRUE  10.68 Widget
## 13:  6  2006          Tax    FALSE 129.21 Widget
```

Comment: You think that `stringr` is useful? Then you should check out `stringi` package :) http://stringi.rexamine.com

Comment: Picking up the combinations and units was helpful, and this was easy to modify to the actual dataset.

Answer (score 2):

This is similar to one of he other answers and distinguishes between line numbers (your [id] column).

```
matches <- regmatches(x,gregexpr("[0-9]{4} [^@]+@ \\$[0-9.]+",x))
lengths <- sapply(matches,length)
z <- unlist(matches)
z <- regmatches(z,regexec("([0-9]{4}) ([^@]+) @ \\$([0-9.]+)",z))

df <- t(sapply(z,function(x)c(year=x[2], number=x[4], cat=x[3])))
df <- data.frame(id=rep(1:length(x),times=lengths),df, stringsAsFactors=F)
df$est <- ifelse(grepl("Est",df$cat),"Est","")
df$cat <- regmatches(df$cat,regexpr("[^ /]+$",df$cat))
df
#    id year number cat est
# 1   1 2001  25.19 Tax    
# 2   1 2002  10.68 Tax Est
# 3   1 2000  55.67 Int Est
# 4   2 1999  81.16 Tax    
# 5   3 1998  52.72 Tax    
# 6   3 2001  62.49 Int Est
# 7   4 1994  68.33 Int    
# 8   4 1993 159.67 Int Est
# 9   5 1993  38.33 Int    
# 10  5 1992 159.67 Int Est
# 11  6 2006 129.21 Tax    
# 12  6 1991  58.19 Tax Est
# 13  6 1991  30.95 Int Est
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, but I found the regmatch unforgiving for misspelled or poorly formatted versions in the actual dataset. Otherwise worked well.

Answer (score 1):

To create exactly the dataframe you are asking for, you can use a few tricks like `strsplit`, regular expressions, and `rbind`.

```
x <- unlist(strsplit(x, ',|;'))
bits <- regmatches(x,gregexpr('(\\d|\\.)+|(Tax|Int|Est)', x))
df <- do.call(rbind, lapply(bits, function(info) {
  data.frame(year = info[[1]], number = tail(info, 1)[[1]],
             cat = if ('Tax' %in% info) 'Tax' else 'Int',
             est = if ('Est' %in% info) 'Est' else '')
}))
df$cat <- factor(df$cat); df$est <- factor(df$est);
```

which gives us

```
   year number cat est
 1 2001  25.19 Tax
 2 2002  10.68 Tax Est
 3 2000  55.67 Int Est
 4 1999  81.16 Tax
 5 1998  52.72 Tax
```

Comment: Wasn't sure how to pick up the combinations in this version.

Answer (score 0):

You can extract the numbers out using:

```
regmatches(x,gregexpr('(\\d)+', x))
```

which yields

```
 [[1]]
 [1] "2001"  "25.19" "2002"  "10.68" "2000"  "55.67"

 [[2]]
 [1] "1999"  "81.16"

 [[3]]
 [1] "1998"  "52.72" "2001"  "62.49"

 [[4]]
 [1] "1994"   "68.33"  "1993"   "159.67"

 [[5]]
 [1] "1993"   "38.33"  "1992"   "159.67"

 [[6]]
 [1] "2006"   "129.21" "1991"   "58.19"  "1991"   "30.95"
```

However, if you can assume every year's info is separated by a `,` or `;`, try this:

```
x <- unlist(strsplit(x, ',|;'))
nums <- regmatches(x,gregexpr('(\\d|\\.)+', x))
df <- data.frame(matrix(as.numeric(unlist(nums)), ncol = 2, byrow = TRUE))
colnames(df) <- c('Year', 'Number')
```

which looks like

```
  Year Number
  1 2001  25.19
  2 2002  10.68
  3 2000  55.67
  4 1999  81.16
  5 1998  52.72
```

Comment: Can you think of a way to sub-distinguish between the years (obviously starting with 19 or 20, no decimals), and the numbers between the "$" and "/" (always with decimal, after @)?  It seems to call for an if expression with different regex, but I can't figure it out.

Comment: `nchar(x) == 4 & !grepl('.', x, fixed = TRUE)`?